# decision tree error in train classification in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decision-tree

```
val pdata = sc.parallelize(Seq(data))
val parsedData = data.map { line => val parts = line.split(',')          LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split('').map(_.toDouble)))}.cache()

// Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

// Train a DecisionTree model.
val numClasses = 2
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = {}
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 5
val maxBins = 32

val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
```

I have written this code to build a decision tree Classification model on my given data. First column is the prediction column.
It throws an error stating that "overloaded method value trainClassifier with alternatives:"

Here is my sample Input data:
1   2   50  12500   98
1   0   13  3250    28
1   1   16  4000    35
1   2   20  5000    45
0   1   24  6000    77
0   4   4   1000    4
1   2   7   1750    14
0   1   12  3000    35
1   2   9   2250    22
1   5   46  11500   98
0   4   23  5750    58

Comment: You're likely to get better/faster answers after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: First, please tag with the relevant tags next time you ask a questions. Answers can't read your mind to know that you are using Apache Spark ! Second of all, would you please care explaining to me what do you think the following line does : `val categoricalFeaturesInfo = {}`?